# How to wait for page evaluation in PhantomJS after assigning custom HTML to page.content

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to add an image's width to itself as an attribute. I need the width as it appears once loaded in the browser. I'm doing this for html email and compatibility with outlook.

Here's the code I have that isn't working as expected:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 1366, height : 768 };
page.content = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Title of Test Website</title></head><body><table><tr style="width: 400px;"><td width="400"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400" alt="" class="img"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400" alt="" class="img"></td></tr></table></body></html>';

var imagePage = page.evaluate(function() {
        var imgs= document.getElementsByClassName('img');
        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            imgs[i].width = imgs[i].width;
        }
    return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
});

console.log(imagePage);
phantom.exit();
```

This returns the page with the width attribute for images added but the width is set to 0. After a bit of testing, this appears to be happening because the page hasn't loaded completely yet. I tried wraping the code in window.load() but that doesn't seem to run with evaluate. Here's an example that works in the browser with the same code: 
http://jsbin.com/suhovabiza/edit?html,js,output

Any ideas on loading that evaluate after the page loads? Looking at the PhantomJS docs this can be done with page.open which has the onLoadFinished callback but that requires a url, I'm working with a string in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually wait for page load by using the `page.open()` callback, but since you're essentially loading a custom about:blank page (by assigning a string to `page.content`), you can listen to the [`onLoadFinished` event](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-load-finished.html) like this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 1366, height : 768 };

page.onLoadFinished = function(){
    page.evaluate(function() {
        var imgs= document.getElementsByClassName('img');
        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            imgs[i].width = imgs[i].width;
        }
    });

    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
};

page.content = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Title of Test Website</title></head><body><table><tr style="width: 400px;"><td width="400"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400" alt="" class="img"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400" alt="" class="img"></td></tr></table></body></html>';
```